# Media Player does not stop when a phone call is received

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, phone-call

MediaPlayer does not pause when a phone call is received. Anyone who any code I could add to fix this. If anyone can help would be great! Only beginner
I have added the on Stop from answer below it works but then if I try to go back with the back button or back button in the action bar to go to main menu of app, it just crashes.

```
public class player1 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_1);
        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound01;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound02;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound03;
        // Listeners
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player1.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); ;         
             progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
             progressBar.setProgress(0);
             progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
             new Thread(this).start();

         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
              mp.seekTo(0);

            }
        });

        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                     mp.pause();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
                  } else {
                     mp.start();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);

                  }

               }
            });
   }
   static boolean runThread = true;
   public void run() {
        while ( runThread )  {
              int currentPosition=0;
              int total = mp.getDuration();
              if ( mp != null && currentPosition <= total )  {
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 return;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 return;
              }            
              progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
           } else
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        runThread = false; 
    }



   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


        if (mp != null)
        if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

       }
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (mp != null){
          if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();
      }

      //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
      //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
      super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
        }
    }
 }
```

Error

```
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.apps.seconds/com.apps.seconds.player1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3463)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3517)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at com.apps.seconds.player1.onStop(player1.java:154)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1212)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5275)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3458)
 09-12 14:52:49.755: E/AndroidRuntime(26104):   ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

When a phone call is received your activity goes in background, and receives a callback in `onStop()`.

So, `onStop()` should do something similar to what `onBackPressed()` does.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: to extend to that, you might want to do `mp.pause()` instead in there and make something similar but with `mp.start()` in the `onStart()`

Comment: Hey I tried this but when the phone call rings it just crashes

Comment: Wait It could have been my fault let me try again

Comment: Hey it works but then if I try to go back with the back button or back button in the action bar it just crashes. Ill post logcat

Comment: See my updated code, use `pause()` instead of `stop()`, as I assume once the music player is in the stopped state you can no longer stop it again, which may be the reason why it crashes when you go back.

Comment: I was using the mp.pause. Any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the error suggests that the `isPlaying()` was called when the media player was in an invalid state. A work around would be to wrap the block from `onStop()` in a `try-catch` block to handle the exception gratefully. However, I wouldn't recommend this hack. Better to spend some time and fix the real cause of the issue.

Comment: If I was going to do that hack how would I go about doing it. Could you show me in your answer or post in the comments

Comment: You would catch the exception, something like this: `try{if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }}catch(Exception e){}`